# Can I store a IAccessible object for later use in my program?

Tags: winapi, accessibility

I have a program that uses MSAA to find a control. Then I want to save that pointer so that later I can get the accessible object again but it never works. Can you store these pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You might try storing the HWND of your control, then later on use AccessibleObjectFromWindow to retrieve the IAccessible object using the HWND.  Could be an option if reusing the IAccessible* is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you mean by "later". If the underlying UI object is gone (because for example, the user closed the owning application), the pointer may still exist but will be useless and will return error codes if used. It's quite logical, you need to clone all data when you get a hold on it.

Here is a bit of official documentation on this: [Receiving Errors for IAccessible Interface Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695701(v=vs.85).aspx)